# Get only one match with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, object, loops, iterator

In the function below I iterate through an array (incidents) which contains of strings. The strings is describing an incident (crime or accidents) that is scrapted from another web app, and what I'm doing is dividing and counting the different crimes / accidents and placing them in an object (INCIDENT_MATCHES).

However, some of the text strings may contain of several of the keywords that I search for (e.g. both "gunfire" and "battery"), but that I don't want. Instead I just want the first found word to be counted, and if more keywords are found they should be ignored.

How could this be done?

```
var INCIDENT_MATCHES = {
    battery: /\w*(bråk)\w*|överfall|slagsmål|slogs|misshandel|misshandlad|\w*(tjuv)\w*/ig,
    burglaries: /snattade|snattare|snatta|inbrott|bestulen|stöld|\w*(tjuv)\w*/ig,
    robberies: /\w*(rån)\w*|personrån|\w*(ryckning)\w*|väskryckt*/ig,
    gunfire: /skottlossning|skjuten|sköt/ig,
    drugs: /narkotikabrott/ig,
    vandalism: /skadegörelse|klotter|\w*(klottra)\w*/ig,
    trafficAccidents: /(trafik|bil)olycka|(trafik|bil)olyckor|\w*(personbil)\w*|singelolycka|kollision|\w*(kollidera)\w*|påkörd|trafik|smitningsolycka/ig,
};

var j = 0,
incidentCounts = {},
incidentTypes = Object.keys(INCIDENT_MATCHES);

incidents.forEach(function(incident) {
    matchFound = false;

    incidentTypes.forEach(function(type) {
        if(typeof incidentCounts[type] === 'undefined') {
            incidentCounts[type] = 0;
        }
        var matchFound = incident.match(INCIDENT_MATCHES[type]);

        if(matchFound){
            matchFound = true;
            incidentCounts[type] += 1;
        }
    });

    j++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return `false` from the "each" handler to stop iteration.

```
    if(matchFound){
        matchFound = true;
        incidentCounts[type] += 1;
        return false;
    }
```

*edit* — and you'll want (I think) another test outside that, at the end of the outer loop:

```
  j++; // I don't understand what that does ...
  if (matchFound) return false;
```

Comment: This actually doesn't stop the count by some reason. The same string are checked for matches again, even after a match is found.

Comment: @holyredbeard ah well maybe you need another `return false;` for the outer "loop" (`.each()`) - I'll update the answer.

Comment: I experimented with your solution and found that changing the second 'forEach' statement to 'every', putting 'return false' inside if(matchFound) and after that putting "else { return true; }" did the trick!

Comment: Thanks for your help with "return false" anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution below to work. What I did was the following:

1. I replaced the second forEach statement with "every"
2. Put "return false" inside "if(matchFound)"
3. Added "else { return true; }" so that the loop continues if no match is found.

**The code:**

```
incidents[2].forEach(function(incident) {
    matchFound = false;

    incidentTypes.every(function(type) {
        if(typeof crimesPerType[type] === 'undefined') {
            crimesPerType[type] = 0;
    }
    var matchFound = incident.match(INCIDENT_MATCHES[type]);

    if(matchFound){
        crimesPerType[type] += 1;
        if (type == 'trafficAccidents') {
            incidents[3][j].push('traffic');
        }
        else {
            incidents[3][j].push('crime');
        }
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});
```